# Projecting shapefile of point geometries?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, point, geometry, feature-class

I am trying to creating a point shapefile that lies within polygon(a feature layer). By creating point geometry objects and filtering the ones that fall within the polygon(feature layer), I created a list (list of point geometry objects as "pointList"). Using CopyFeature_management tool, I created a shapefile out of "pointList". But this doesnot have projection and the attributes has FID, Shape and ID(all 0).

How could I project this point shapefile, the same projection as that of polygon?

Here is what I have so far, (where the extent is calculated for polygon feature layer):

```
pointList =[]
m=0
     x = random.uniform(extent.XMin, extent.XMax)
     y = random.uniform(extent.YMin, extent.YMax)
     points = arcpy.Point(x, y)
     pointGeo = arcpy.PointGeometry(points)  #creates point geometry object
     polygon = arcpy.Polygon(polygon_array)  #polygon object
     pointWithin = pointGeo.within(polygon)  #gives boolean output. 
     if pointWithin == True:
         m = m + 1
         pointList.append(pointGeo)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(pointList, outpath)
```

Comment: You will have to abandon copyfeatures. Get the CRS from your polygon feature class with arcpy.Describe(polygon).spatialReference, create a new feature class with CreateFeatureclass_management (insert CRS here), add your intended fields (X_coord, Y_coord) and use an arcpy.da.InsertCursor on your new feature class with ['shape@XY','X_coord','Y_coord'] as fields then insert new rows with ((x,y),x,y) if pointWithin - the first element is a tuple of X and Y then values for the fields X_Coord and Y_Coord. Or you can use fields ['Shape@','X_coord','Y_coord'] and insert (points,x,y) on your cursor..

Comment: Do I start  arcpy.da.InsertCursor (for new point featureclass )inplace of line where I am appending the list after the True condition? Doing so is giving me syntax error for that particular line. Thanks much for the feedback @MichaelStimson.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
import os, arcpy
SR = arcpy.SpatialReference(EPSG_Code)     # set this to match your data
outpath = r'c:\your\path\to\shapefile.shp' # set this to match your data

# create an empty point feature class
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(os.path.dirname(outpath),os.path.basename(outpath),"POINT",spatial_reference=SR)
# add the desired fields to store your coordinate info
arcpy.AddField_management(outpath,'X_Coord','DOUBLE')
arcpy.AddField_management(outpath,'Y_Coord','DOUBLE')

# if your polygon array doesn't change then set it here
# rather than rebuilding on each iteration
polygon = arcpy.Polygon(polygon_array)  #polygon object
polygon.spatial_reference = SR          # assuming the same spatial reference

with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outpath,['SHAPE@XY','X_Coord','Y_Coord']) as ICur:
    x = random.uniform(extent.XMin, extent.XMax)
    y = random.uniform(extent.YMin, extent.YMax)
    point       = arcpy.Point(x, y)
    pointGeo    = arcpy.PointGeometry(points)  #creates point geometry object
    pointGeo.spatial_reference = SR            # set the spatial reference of this point
    if pointGeo.within(polygon):
        # we want to keep this one because it's within
        # the focus polygon, now insert this row
        ICur.insertRow( ((x,y),x,y) )
        # note the brackets are important, the first is for insertRow
        # the second is for the row tuple and the third is for the X,Y
        # tuple required by SHAPE@XY.
```

The projection is defined when you create the shapefile (or GDB feature class) using [Create Feature Class](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002p000000). Then establish an [insert cursor](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/InsertCursor/018w0000000t000000/) (`arcpy.da`) in a with block so that the objects and locks will be cleaned up automatically on exit; in the help it states

> When using InsertCursor on a point feature class, creating a
>   PointGeometry and setting it to the SHAPE@ token is a comparatively
>   expensive operation. Instead, define the point feature using tokens
>   such as SHAPE@XY, SHAPE@Z, and SHAPE@M for faster, more efficient
>   access.

So although we're creating a point geometry and setting its spatial reference it will only be used to test for `within`, if speed isn't of interest then by all means declare your insert cursor as `with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outpath,['SHAPE@','X_Coord','Y_Coord']) as ICur:` then your insert row would be `ICur.insertRow( (pointGeo,x,y) )`.

If your points are in a different spatial reference to your polygons you can use the `PointGeometry.projectAs(different_spatial_reference_object)` to project to match your polygons; this method is valid for [PointGeometry objects](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/PointGeometry/018z00000039000000/) and not [Point objects](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Point/018z0000006t000000/).